# Unity иногда появляется hold on

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иногда при работе в Unity появляется вот такое окно (Не обязательно AddComponentWindow.MouseUp, но всегда с таким заголовком) и тогда Unity полностью зависает и я не могу даже сохранить проект(, и приходится перезапускать. Я искал такую проблему в интернете, но решения так и не нашёл (AutoRefresh - off, не помогает).

Comment: А если подождать 2-3 минуты?

Comment: Твой ПК не обрабатывает эти операции за макросекунду и вот когда ты видишь это окно, значит твой процессор пытается выполнить эту задачу

Comment: "Холд он" = "Подожди некоторое время, я работаю". Это не проблема -- это нормальная работа юнити. Хочешь минимизировать время показа такого окна - обнови компьютер.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это as Designed behavior

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло вот это решение:

**https://forum.unity.com/threads/hold-on-busy-for-too-long.1075210/**

т.е. удалить файл ProjectName/Library/ShaderCache.db
, который у меня был аж целых 8 гигов.

С уважением